# Writing to Google sheet from CSV add single quote in beginning

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using python to get some data from database to csv and from csv to google sheet (sheet1).
When I write data from CSV to google sheet, it add a single quote in beginning of all values which changing integer, date to string. In CSV values doesn't have any single in beginning.

```
with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)  # Skip the header row
    data = list(csv_reader)

# Get existing records from the Google Sheet
worksheet.append_rows(data)
```

Values I expect

```
141872  2000    11/30/2023 10:11
```

Values written to Google sheet

```
'141872 '2000   '11/30/2023 10:11
```

Is there anyway to avoid adding single quote, want to write it as it is in CSV

Comment: The values aren't different. Spreadsheets must guess what kind of data a user just typed, so they'll convert anything that looks as a number or date. A single leading quote is used to tell the spreadsheet the value is text, not a number or date.

Comment: Change the valueInputOption to `USER_ENTERED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about modifying as follows?

#### From:

```
worksheet.append_rows(data)
```

#### To:

```
worksheet.append_rows(data, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

#### Reference:

- [append_rows](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.1.0/api.html?highlight=append_rows#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.append_rows)